How can I change boot logo for my device
I am a computer enthusiast, and I wanted to change my boot logo in my computer recently. I had checked the internet and did researches. But, I couldn't find a good answer throughout the internet. My computer's BIOS mode is UEFI, which meets the requirement of most answers I found in the internet. And, the next step the internet told me is to download HackBGRT and disable secure boot. But, I am looking for a solution that does not involve in any third party app or disabling secure boot. I know command prompt/powershell well. So, if you have any solutions that relates to these root systems, please let me know, thank you
MY COMPUTER DATA
Host Name:                 **********************
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 11 Home
OS Version:                10.0.22631 N/A Build 22631
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          ******
Registered Organization:   N/A
Product ID:                *************************
Original Install Date:     17/1/2023, 3:22:33
System Boot Time:          11/9/2024, 14:09:31
System Manufacturer:       ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
System Model:              VivoBook_ASUSLaptop K3402ZA_S3402ZA
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
BIOS Version:              American Megatrends International, LLC. K3402ZA.312, 13/3/2024
Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Hotfix(s):                 5 Hotfix(s) Installed.


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You say "You are having a problem with boot logo" but you don't say WHAT the problem is that you're having with it. Please EDIT your post and make it more clear the problem you are experiencing.

@DrMoishePippik I understand that it is similar, but the answer for that is downloading HP repairment tools. But I have an ASUS Vivobook computer, I cannot do that

@KamMax, how would anyone know that, if you have not put vital data in the question? Edit the question.

I assume your OS is Windows?

I just edited the question. Now, there is vital data in the question

You can not without disabling integrity checks and these most likely cannot be performed without first disabling Secure Boot.
Modifying boot files will break their file integrity.
This will cause Windows to fail to boot with those checks enabled.
Preventing modification of boot files as shipped by the OEM is the point of secure boot.
I "think" (someone here REALLY knows) that a new hash which also accounts for your logo change would need to be used somehow to generate a new secure boot key and assign it.  I don't think normal mortals do this.

How about disabling secure boot, then how can I change my boot logo. And, Can I change it back?

Then, how can I change a new hash also for my logo change, that's I made a post here...

As mentioned, you can not.  A "secure boot" does not allow modification without internal knowledge of how to set keys.  If you really want a custom logo, disable secure boot and leave it disabled.  You will need to work around it with each windows install.

@SeñorCMasMas - As you correctly point out Secure Boot prevent unsigned or untrussed modifications to the system.  While it might be possible to change the boot logo, if you don't use approved tools that result in a secure signed environment, you will be required to turn off Secure Boot or otherwise make other concessions.
